# Prove that this map lies in Aut L

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $=(,)$,$∈(,)$, prove that the map $L$ to itself defined by $\sigma(z)=-gz^tg$ belongs to Aut$(L)$. When $n=2$, $g$=identity matrix, prove that this automorphism is inner.

The first part is clear to me. When $n=2$,and $g$ is the identity matrix, it is easy to see that $\sigma(x)=-y,\sigma(y)=-x, \sigma(h)=-h$, where $x=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$,$y=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$,
$h=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ comprise the basis of $L$. I was looking at the answers here ([Automorphism in the special linear algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(F)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469841/automorphism-in-the-special-linear-algebra-mathfraksl-2f), [Inner automorphism of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,k)$, $\operatorname{char}(k)=0$ and adjoint action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466479/inner-automorphism-of-mathfraksl2-k-operatornamechark-0-and-adjoi/466525#466525)) but I still don't understand a couple of things. How is $(adX)^n=0$ for $n\geq 3$ when $X$ is nilpotent? Also, how can we write $\sigma$=exp(ad$x$)expad$(-y)$expad$x$, thereby concluding that $\sigma$ is an inner automorphism?

Comment: It is not possible for me to provide all the details, but here's a bit of the background: https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2012/08/18/automorphisms-of-lie-algebras/

Comment: A nilpotent $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ satisfies $A^3=0$. So ${\rm ad}^3(x)=0$ here.